# Sleep or not to sleep

Tags: road-bike, long-distance

I am planning to have a tour 230km with roady bike, elevation <600m overall.
I think with average speed will be ~20-25 kmh
What you recommend should I sleep on half of ride? Are you talking about sleeping or just have a 1 hour break?
Problem is if I will start 7a.m I need min, 14 hour to finish. I don't want to ride  at night.
Please share your recommendations.

Note: I have SPD-SL pedals, and all other dress code :)

Comment: Your question could do with some editing as it's quite hard to follow. I think your question is do I need to take a break if riding for 14+ hours? I'm afraid only you will actually know the answer as we're all different. I would probably take a short break after every 3 hours if time wasn't critical and cycle through the distance.

Comment: If you're cycling at 20km/h, 230km will only take 11.5h in the saddle, so are you planning some extended rests?

Comment: 230km in 14 hours is 16.4km/hr with no breaks, which is a pretty low pace for a ride that long. Which is not to criticize your expected pace, just pointing out you'll probably actually move much faster than that, more in the 20-23kph range, making the ride < 12 hours saddle time. You probably shouldn't need or plan on sleeping in that time, but as Dan K points out, if it's not a race, just a pleasure ride or Randonée, you should plan on short breaks of at least a few minutes every few hours to stretch your back etc.

Comment: What do SPD pedals have to do with sleeping?

Comment: Food and fluild intake will be more important than sleep.  If this is not managed you will need a 'sleep' break to give your body time to replenish.

Comment: Please refrain from sleeping while riding your bike.  Always stop and get off before sleeping.

Comment: Your profile says you are in Germany, if we take Munich as an example of the southern end in this near solstice time of year you have 16 hours of daylight between 05:13 and 21:14.  So start at 05:00 and you'll have two hours of buffer if the ride turns out slower than planned.  Also get some lights and practice using them in familiar settings in the evening.

Comment: Whats the longest ride you've ever done, in time, and in distance ?   600m elevation is comparatively small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can maintain 20-25km/h riding speed over 230km, that's 9-12 hours of riding time. If your stops are efficient, you can easily achieve that in daylight hours in summer. I still recommend you take lights to be seen by at dusk, and in case you're delayed by a mechanical. You're not likely to be riding for long enough to be sleepy at the half way (or better, 2/3) point. If the distance is much longer than you're used to, your speed will decline and your need for rest will increase. You may then have to stop if you don't want to ride in the dark. Aiming to stop for around 20 minutes every 3 hours, and extending one stop for a proper meal is a fairly typical approach, though many would stop less or more briefly.

You use the word "tour". If that means more luggage than you're used to, then you should probably reduce your speed estimate a little, though your ride is essentially flat, to take account of extra drag.

200km in (max) 14 hours including stops is randoneuring (audax) pace, and the pace is very doable of the distance is. Example :My first 200km (230km including getting there and back) was well under that, despite being a winter ride (always slower).

Comment: This will be first time long distance (normally I am riding 20km but too high with long brakes) but Unfortunately I have no partner with me.. Are you recommend take first time long dist. ride alone?

Comment: My first 200km was not in a group; I rode with others for odd bits of the ride, but the more experienced riders were almost all quicker than me.  Now I do 200-400km days solo every month or so.  But before that I had done quite a lot of 60-160km rides on my own so was happy with the self-sufficiency aspect.  The step from 20km to 200km is a really big one; if you haven't ridden over 100km in one go before you will need recovery time off the bike, and you won't maintain anything like the 20 km/h average in the question - in that case you should plan for a sleep stop.

Comment: Many thanks for comments, Yes I have the same plan.. to have more and more long distance rides.. unfortunately I live in mountain area. this 20km is equal to others 70km I think :))
And my road bike components are not supper pupper, just BTWIN Triban 300

Answer (score 2):

You need to honestly evaluate your expected performance and endurance on a >200km ride.

You'll need to figure out an expected average speed, and a schedule of breaks that you will need, then calculate the total time needed to complete the ride. Build in a margin of error in case you go slower than expected or need longer breaks.

If the the total amount of time need to complete the ride will mean you are forced to ride in the dark, or you feel it's too long an effort, then split the ride over two days and stop somewhere for the night.